# Unit testing Number with should.js fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I've got this (mongoose) class (this syntax being coffeescript):

```
Entry = new mongoose.Schema
   duration: Number
```

I am explicitly setting the duration property with an integer (or a decimal, the result is the same):

```
entry = new Entry
entry.duration = 1
```

I am saving this mongoose entity:

```
entry.save
```

But when testing the resulting entity returned by a findOne, I cannot get the duration property to pass my unit test:

```
doc.duration.should.eql 1
```

This always returns:

```
AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 1
```

As said before, I get this result with a value of 1 or 1.5
The doc returned by the findOne is exactly the entity I saved just before.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The right way to unit test a property of type Number on a Mongoose Schema class is:

```
doc.duration.valueOf().should.eql 1
```

So calling the valueOf() method on the property returns the value of the property. Simply returning the property returns an Object.